# Get path to Solr instanceDir with solrj

Tags: solr, solrj

How can I get path to an instanceDir with solrj?

I know the path to SOLR_HOME and I know the actual name of the collection but the actual instanceDir of the collection might be different.
e.g. the collection with the name "foo" maybe in the directory `solr_home/foobar_1/` or in `solr_home/foobar_0/`

So how can I find out if the directory of this collection is called foobar_1 or foobar_0 with solrj?

Comment: areyou talking about cores?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is how to get the [InstanceDir](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Defining+core.properties#Definingcore.properties-Placementofcore.properties) of a solr core with solrj.

The corresponding URL to get this information is:

- via [Core Admin API](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/CoreAdmin+API#CoreAdminAPI-STATUS): 
  http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=STATUS&core=myCore
- or via [Core Overview](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Core-Specific+Tools): http://localhost:8983/solr/myCore/admin/system

This code use solrj to get the information:

```java
    SolrClient client = new HttpSolrClient("http://localhost:8983/solr/");
    String core = "myCore";

    // Core Admin API
    CoreAdminRequest status = new CoreAdminRequest();
    status.setAction(CoreAdminAction.STATUS);
    status.setCoreName(core);
    CoreAdminResponse rspStatus = status.process(client);
    String instanceDirCore = (String) rspStatus.getCoreStatus().findRecursive(core, "instanceDir");
    System.out.println(instanceDirCore);

    // Core Overview
    GenericSolrRequest system = new GenericSolrRequest(METHOD.GET, "/admin/system", new ModifiableSolrParams());
    SimpleSolrResponse rsp = system.process(client, core);
    String instanceDir = (String) rsp.getResponse().findRecursive("core", "directory", "instance");
    System.out.println(instanceDir);

    assert instanceDir.equals(instanceDirCore);
```